# Limit gsutil -m threads

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Is there a way to limit the number of threads a `gsutil -m` command spawns? Can I say something like `gsutil -m --threads=4` to spawn exactly four threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set the `parallel_thread_count` and `parallel_process_count` values in the boto configuration file to 4

[Gsutil Top-Level Command-Line Options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions?hl=ru)

> -m flag
>
> Causes supported operations (acl ch, acl set, cp, mv, rm, rsync, and
>   setmeta) to run in parallel. This can significantly improve
>   performance if you are performing operations on a large number of
>   files over a reasonably fast network connection.
>
> **gsutil performs the specified operation using a combination of
>   multi-threading and multi-processing, using a number of threads and
>   processors determined by the parallel_thread_count and
>   parallel_process_count values set in the boto configuration file.** You
>   might want to experiment with these values, as the best values can
>   vary based on a number of factors, including network speed, number of
>   CPUs, and available memory.
>
> Using the -m option may make your performance worse if you are using a
>   slower network, such as the typical network speeds offered by
>   non-business home network plans. It can also make your performance
>   worse for cases that perform all operations locally (e.g., gsutil
>   rsync, where both source and destination URLs are on the local disk),
>   because it can "thrash" your local disk.
>
> If a download or upload operation using parallel transfer fails before
>   the entire transfer is complete (e.g. failing after 300 of 1000 files
>   have been transferred), you will need to restart the entire transfer.
>
> Also, although most commands will normally fail upon encountering an
>   error when the -m flag is disabled, all commands will continue to try
>   all operations when -m is enabled with multiple threads or processes,
>   and the number of failed operations (if any) will be reported as an
>   exception at the end of the command's execution.